# Ember CLI dependencies are undefined (moment is undefined)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, momentjs, ember-cli

I am using version 0.0.46 of Ember CLI.

In my bower.json file I have defined

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.7.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.7",
    "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0",
    "interact": "~1.0.26",
    "moment": "2.8.3"
  }
}
```

Did a bower install which loaded moment into bower_components. And in my Brocfile.js I have imported it.

```
app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

And in my .jshintrc I have included it.

```
"predef": [{
  "document": true,
  "window": true,
  "-Promise": true,
  "moment": true
}]
```

And I created an application route just to see about getting it working.

```
import Ember from "ember";

var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  currentDate: null,
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.set('currentDate', moment());
  }
});

export default ApplicationRoute;
```

It comes back saying moment is undefined. I have tried with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and [interactjs](http://interactjs.io/) but neither want to work.

I tried adding

```
/* global moment */
```

to the application route. I also tried

```
/* global moment:true */
```

but still nothing.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug in version 0.0.46 of Ember CLI?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested and it works fine for me. Only catch is that you have to kill the `ember serve` process and restart when editing the brocfile. have you tried that?

Comment: Indeed I have. Several times. Tried creating new apps as well to see if I buggered some config. To no avail..

Comment: I have a project on 0.0.46 that works fine with moment.  Most likely some sort of local environment issue.

Comment: strange... I justed with a new app and it worked fine. If you open the devtools console and type `moment` do you get anything back?

Comment: I was getting the same, then I found out that you need to restart and do "ember serve" again as the autoload doesn't account for newly imported bower components.

Answer (score 2):

Well I went ahead and updated all the things (node and bower), created a new app and was able to get it to work. So it is something to do with some config that didn't update properly when I upgraded Ember CLI and did an ember init. I'll dig in and see what config isn't happy.

Found the problem. There were some old files sitting inside the public/assets folder (vendor.js vendor.css appname.js appname.css) that were causing unknown conflicts. Deleted those and bam, it works.